# custom code written for ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessor not being hit all the time

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1 and SQL server is used for xDB.
in below code I'm adding custom values and this gets executed when I close the browser and interaction is being added into xConnect by default by sitecore.

now my question is that it is not being hit all the time when I close the browser.

there is no consistency some time it gets executed post closing browser in 5 min, sometime in 10 min, sometime 20 min or some time dont get executed.

Please advise.

```
public class ConvertInteractionFacet : ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessorBase
    {
        private ILogger _logMessage;

        public override void Process(ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipelineArgs args)
        {
            _logMessage = new Logger();
            _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: start ConvertInteractionFacet process12345");
            try
            {
                string planCode = string.Empty;
                string planMemberId = string.Empty;
                string userId = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    var memberActiveAccount = string.Empty;
                    if (Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session != null && Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUserDetails"] != null)
                    {
                        var currentUserDetails = ((UserDetails)Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUserDetails"]);

                        planMemberId = ((PlanMemberAccount)currentUserDetails.MemberAccounts).PlanMemberId.ToString();
                        planCode = ((PlanMemberAccount)currentUserDetails.MemberAccounts).PlanCode.ToString();
                        userId = currentUserDetails.UserId;
                        _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: plan member id is " + planMemberId + " and Plan code is " + planCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: plan member id not in session");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    _logMessage.Log(LogType.Error, "Error12345.GetActivePlanMemberAccount: " + ex.Message);
                }

                if (args != null && args.XConnectInteraction.Events.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("PlanCode"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("PlanCode", planCode);

                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("PlanMemberId"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("PlanMemberId", planMemberId);

                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("SessionId"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("SessionId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("UserId"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("UserId", userId);

                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("CorrelationId"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("CorrelationId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    if (!args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.ContainsKey("TimeStamp"))
                        args.XConnectInteraction.Events[0].CustomValues.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
                }
                _logMessage.Log(LogType.Info, "Info: end ConvertInteractionFacet process12345");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logMessage.Log(LogType.Error, "Error12345: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for testing can you reduce the session timeout to 1 minute. Default value is 20 . <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">

Comment: the above configuration is on web.config. If is working fine I will explain you in an answer.

Comment: Hi Vald, thanks a lot for response. yes now I can see debugger coming within a minute. I tried twice and both the time debugger came and code executed successfully. Please now let me know what was happening when it was 20 min like sometime never executed.

Comment: Hi Vlad, will it behave same if I will use it with session statemode = outproc and redis as session state provider.

Comment: @AlokKumar is not recommended to change the value in production, for local environment/testing is fine to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore is keeping the information about the contact in the session until session is ended. The default value is 20 minutes until it is expiring and save the data into xdb.

You have two option to write data faster into xdb:

1. Change the timeout for session to 1 minute. This is recommended just
   for testing , is not recommended to reduce the value in production
2. Also for testing is recommended to have a page which is called to flush the data from session into xDB.
   Please add next content to the page and save it like **Abandon.aspx**:

   ```
    <%@ Page language="c#" %> <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>   <head>

   <title>Abandon Page</title></head> 
   <body>  <script runat="server"> 

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Cancel();           
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
   } 
   </script>
   ```

Save abandon.aspx into your root folder and call it to save data from Session in Xdb.